# Use MultiPart in Retrofit Get Value Error

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I want to post my image to server.

I used Multipart.Part by Retrofit2

Header value is correct But Image Data value get crash value

[image]

like this value

Why this Happened??

I need to post value by form-data

I find it for very very many time....!
Plz help me

here is my code

```
            val filePath = fileUri.path
            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            resizeBitmap(filePath, 512, 512)?.
            compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream)
            val file = File(filePath!!)
            val fileToUpload = run {
                val requestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_image", file.name, requestBody)
            }
            APIUserProfileImage.request(requestable, fileToUpload) {
                Log.v("SUCCESS1", "SUCCESS1")
            }


private fun resizeBitmap(photoPath: String?, targetW: Int, targetH: Int): Bitmap? {
    val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, bmOptions)
    val photoW = bmOptions.outWidth
    val photoH = bmOptions.outHeight
    var scaleFactor = 1
    if (targetW > 0 || targetH > 0) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH)
    }
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, bmOptions)
}
```

for API

```
@Multipart
@POST
fun requestMultipart(@Url endPoint: String, @Part file: MultipartBody.Part) : Call<String>
```

I found all of kinds happened

and server is working fine( + post key value is "profile_image"

Answer (score 3):

You should use like this

```
@Multipart
@POST
fun requestMultipart(@Url endPoint: String, @Part profile_image: MultipartBody.Part) : Call<String>
```

instead of

```
@Multipart
@POST
fun requestMultipart(@Url endPoint: String, @Part file: MultipartBody.Part) : Call<String>
```

Comment: I changed it
but same result value... what's wrong?

Comment: Can you show your error log?